# Why this code works with jquery 1.3.2 but not with 1.4.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

**this code**

```
var tip = "<p class='adobe-reader-download'>Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
tip +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";


if($("div#maincontent a[href*='.pdf']").length>0){
    $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
```

**works fine with this**

```
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**but not working with this**

```
<script 
type="text/jscript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Well for one you haven't escaped the double quotes around `adobe-reader-download`.

Comment: i dont know why. but maybe because your if is not closed..

PS: you can get rid of the ">0" it works without it :P

Comment: You don't really explain much about what it is that doesn't work. Have you tried poking around with Firebug to see what's going on?  Does the DOM get modified at all? Are there errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var tip = "<p class='adobe-reader-download'>Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";

            tip += " href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";


            if ($("div#maincontent a[href*='.pdf']").length > 0) {
                $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
            }
        });
```

with this:

```
<div id="maincontent">
    <a href="sample.pdf">your pdf</a>
</div>
```

for outputs with jq 1.4:

Your pdf

Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download Adobe Reader.

Comment: still not working with 1.4.2 . this classname  `class='adobe-reader-download'` works with 1.3.2

Comment: the problem must be something else.

Comment: Xgreen -  :) problem was different in link of jquery 1.4 type was `type="text/jscript"' not `type="text/javascript"` sorry for inconvenience. Should i delete this question. or i should accept any answer

Comment: you could just accept answer. its better for me :) glad you worked it out

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does the tip not get appended to the page? Does the link for the tip not work? Be a bit more descriptive when you say it "doesn't work", tell us how.

I've made an example of this code here: http://jsbin.com/akugo/edit

With JSBin you can tell it what version of jQuery to use, and I've tested it using 1.3.2 and 1.4.2 and I don't see any problems. The only thing I changed from the code you posted is that I closed the "if" statement with a bracket ( "}" ).